# Group columns into one column

Tags: sql

I have a select like

```
Select b.BookingID, c.CustName, c.CustEmail, c.CustAdd
from  Booking b
INNER JOIN Customer c ON b.CustID = c.CustID

Booking Id | CustName | CustEmail | CustAdd
1          | Wes Sk   | Wes@Gmail | 18 Blah
```

How can I merge columns to produce

```
Booking Id | Cust
1          | Wes Sk Wes@Gmail 18 Blah
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the fields in your query.

```
Select b.BookingID, c.CustName + ' ' + c.CustEmail + ' ' + c.CustAdd As Cust
from  Booking b
INNER JOIN Customer c ON b.CustID = c.CustID
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work with oracle and postgresql. For MSSQL you can use the '+' sign instead '||'.

```
SELECT b.BookingID, c.CustName || ' ' || c.CustEmail || ' ' || c.CustAdd AS Cust
FROM Booking b
INNER JOIN Customer c ON b.CustID = c.CustID
```